# Intuitive basis for linear transformations (2D/3D matrices)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition, geometric-interpretation

Can every possible linear transformation, at least in 2 or 3 dimensions, be expressed as a simple sequence of scaling, rotation, stretch-squeeze, and reflection?

Comment: You can watch [3Blue1Brown's Essence of Linear Algebra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjBOesZCoqc&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab)

Comment: @JohnGlenn is there a specific concept amongst those hours of videos that you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Every linear transformation corresponds to a matrix and we know that we can decompose a matrix into its SVD decomposition.

$$A = U\Sigma V^T$$

The orthogonal matrices corresponds to rotation and reflection.

The diagonal matrix corresponds to scaling, stretch-squeeze. However, note that sum singular values can be zero. Hence this corresponds to projection to lower dimensional space.